# Vim: How to get a list of all commands that start with typed letter?

Tags: vim, command

I'm currently making a transition from RubyMine to Vim and have a question regarding [this video](https://youtu.be/LdNac8uSzaw?t=219).

As u can see the guy types <kbd>G</kbd> and after that another key to get a list of all commands starting with the letter <kbd>G</kbd>.

I've been searching for a solution for quite a while now but couldn't find anything useful.

Thank's a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you try clicking the 'tab' button, maybe twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He must be typing `<C-d>` in the video. That’s a *very* handy sequence for completing. Useful for things like searching for help, too. And not just things that *start* with the string. E.g.,

```
:h rewi<C-d>
:rewind                   :trewind
:brewind                  :ptrewind
:crewind                  :sbrewind
:lrewind                  :tabrewind
:srewind                  tlib#vim#RestoreWindow()
```

Comment: Awesome! Thats it! Also thanks to Sagar for ur efforts.

Answer (score 2):

`:<letter>`<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

And then, use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate.

This will list all the commands starting with the letter you typed.

More on commands history...

```
q:
```

Lists all the commands you typed.

`:g/<your starting letter>/`

And then use the above command, to get a list of the command starting with the letter of your preference.

Go to the command you want and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, if you want to execute that command.

Comment: Well, when I use the arrow key or tab I can browse through all the commands that start with the letter one at a time but I don't get a list.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, tab will only show me the commands one at a time but I don't get a list like the guy in the video. :(

Comment: Which version of the vim do you use?

Tab works for me.

Comment: I'm using version 7.4.769.